# Why disabling interrupts achieves mutual exclusion in uni-processor systems?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, operating-system, locking

Section 28.5 of [the Locks Chapter](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/threads-locks.pdf) of the OSTEP book shows that disabling interrupts achieves mutual exclusion among threads in uni-processor systems. I don't get it: what if the thread holding the lock calls some system calls in the critical section? In this case, it relinquishes CPU before releasing the lock and thus another thread waiting for the lock may enter the critical section as well. I went through the section but couldn't find an answer.

According to the Slide 2 of another [lecture notes](https://homes.cs.washington.edu/~arvind/cs422/lectureNotes/l6-6.pdf), `Internal events are thread does something to relinquish the CPU` and `Preventing internal events is easy`. Then Slide 3 explains the same locking implementation by disabling interrupts as the one in the OSTEP book.

Although I'm sort of confirmed that it is indeed necessary to consider the case where the thread holding the lock relinquishes CPU by itself, I still have two questions:

1. why does the implementation in both of the above references consider disabling interrupts only while ignoring the internal events handling?
2. why are internal events easy to prevent? How to achieve it? The only solution I came up with was to prevent the thread from calling any system calls in the critical section, which is too restrictive in my opinion.

Can anyone share wisdom with me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> why are internal events easy to prevent?

You quoted a lecture slide:

> According to the Slide 2 of another lecture notes, Internal events are thread does something to relinquish the CPU

"Thread *does* something to relinquish the CPU." E.g., Thread makes a blocking system call.  You can prevent that from happening by *not writing code* that would relinquish the CPU while inside the critical section.

Comment: Do you mean that it's totally the programmer's responsibility not to write any code that relinquish the CPU in critical section? When he does that and some bad behavior happens, it's completely his fault and we should not blame the OS?

Comment: @ZLW, It is the programmer's responsibility to write code that works. When you're dealing with a primitive real-time OS on a microcontroller, that's how you write code that works.  When you're dealing with a desktop/server/mobile operating system that has full-preemptive scheduling and multiple processors, you do it by using mutexes.

Comment: @ZLW: A quality OS should include a list of system calls that are safe for use within a critical region, and a list of those that are not.  Similar situations arise in cooperative-multitasking systems like the Classic Macintosh OS.  Unlocked objects identified by managed handles may be relocated by any operation that allocates memory, but code may acquire the address of such an object and use it without locking it first if no intervening operations allocate memory nor yield control to any operation that might do so.  There's a list of calls that are "safe" in such contexts.

Answer (score 1):

No explicit locks (as in mutexes or spinlocks) are needed on uni-processor systems to achieve exclusive access to something for a short amount of time. By temporarily disabling interrupts you can stop the thread scheduler (because it's interrupt-driven) and so no other thread will be able to preempt the code that runs with disabled interrupts. It's that simple.

However, the system may provide mechanisms that trigger thread scheduling by means other than interrupts. Say, there's a yield operation that does just that, blocks the current thread and unblocks another one that can run. Therefore, the code that disables interrupts to achieve exclusive/atomic access must not use any such operations because they will either break the exclusive access or even deadlock the system (following yield, the other thread may run with interrupts disabled indefinitely unless interrupts are reenabled somehow again during the thread switch).

Comment: thanks for your answer. Do you mean that it's the programmer's responsibility not to write any yield operation in the critical section? Does the OS not warn the programmer at all when the programmer writes a yield in the critical section?

Comment: @ZLW If you can arbitrarily disable and enable interrupts, you can screw up the system already. A warning (which I can't quite imagine if I take your words literally) may be too little too late.

Comment: @ZLW: When I've written cooperative schedulers, I've usually included a safety-check to detect re-entrant execution, though the only thing that can practically be done once it's detected is to kill execution with a diagnostic.  In most cases where operations yield, they'll need other task to do something before they can proceed, so a need to yield within a critical section would imply that code is going to either crash, deadlock, or violate the requirements of the critical section, and the only thing the OS could hope to do is choose which of those bad outcomes occurs.